# How to Low-Level Caching ? Cache key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching

I want to implement low level cache on my application but I'm having some troubles following the documentation. This is what they have as example:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def competing_price
    Rails.cache.fetch("#{cache_key}/competing_price", expires_in: 12.hours) do
      Competitor::API.find_price(id)
    end
  end
end
```

My questions are:

- How am I suppose to get that variable *cache_key*? Should be given somehow via rails cache or should I have my pre-builded key?
- I'm not sure if I clearly understood how this works, confirm if this logic is correct: I set this for example on my controller to generate a ton of variables. And then every time a variable is requested (from view for example), the controller instead of recalculating it every time (long query) will retrieve the pre-made query in case the key haven't changed. If the key has changed it will recalculate again all variables inside the cache block.

Comment: There used to be a method `cache_key` in Active Record, but not anymore. Certainly [not in rails 4](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/cache_key). What is it that you want to do, ultimately?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have a bunch of variables that are calculated each time a visitor comes to a site, the idea is to generate these variables inside the cache block, to save resources and optimize performance. They should be recalculated only when the key changes I think I can generate the key myself without problem. (example- when a new event / product is created)

Comment: So there, you answered the question yourself: implement `cache_key` method yourself, such that it will invalidate itself when changes occur.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ok so the second part of question about the logic (method of work) is like how I am thinking?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev as per the link you included, it was moved to `ActiveRecord::Integration`.

Comment: @ace the `cache_key` is a ActiveRecord method, so it'll be set on each of your models. So Rails will first query the record in the DB, get its `updated_at` date, and then ask the cache for it. If the cache doesn't have that value, only then will it be calculated from the server.

Comment: @RichardSeviora: yeah, I didn't have any AR apps lying around, else I would have checked. :)

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord::Integration` includes the `cache_key` method in Rails 4. It should be included by default in the standard Rails configuration. To test this, pop open console, get a record and call `cache_key` on it.

Reference on the method is available [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Integration/cache_key).

It will usually generate a string similar to `"#{record.class.name.underscore}/#{record.to_param}-#{record.updated_at}"`. This key-based invalidation approach lets you avoid a lot of the effort involved by simply looking for a cache value based on whenever the record was last updated. Old cache values will be ignored because they're not being retrieved.

DHH wrote a great article on the topic [here](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works).